# Uso dei tre tipi di virgolette in italiano

Tags: punctuation

In generale esistono tre tipi di virgolettatura:

1. le virgolette alte, " ";
2. le virgolette basse, « »;
3. gli apici ' '

La virgolettatura si usa solitamente per riferire del discorso diretto, per indicare una citazione o per segnalare una parola o frase che identifica una certa fonte (sia essa un giornale, un libro o qualcosa di simile).

Personalmente credo di utilizzare sempre le prime in quanto quelle basse mi risultano poco pratiche da digitare (semplice pigrizia) mentre gli apici non mi paiono appropriati allo scopo. Di fatto uso gli apici veramente di rado e magari solo nel caso di citazioni innestate.

Ora, le fonti web più autorevoli che si possano trovare, [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/virgolette_(La_grammatica_italiana)/) e [Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/punteggiatura), non sembrano identificare una netta distinzione tra le tipologie di virgoletta. A me pare però che, forse complice l'utilizzo di dispositivi a tastiera digitale e l'aumentata pigrizia di tutti quando scriviamo, gli apici la facciano da padroni.

Mi sbaglio? Esiste una distinzione precisa nell'uso dei tre tipi?

Comment: Abbozzo di risposta: più che gli apici io personalmente vedo prevalere le virgolette alte, ma a parte questo, tra le alte e le basse non c'è una distinzione accettata universalmente. Per esperienza, ogni casa editrice ha le sue norme redazionali che tra l'altro prescrivono quali virgolette usare (per esempio, sempre «» a meno di virgolette all'interno di virgolette nel qual caso si usano “”; oppure «» per i dialoghi e “” per parole usate in senso “improprio”; e così via). Infine, la vera pigrizia consiste nell'usare "" anziché “” e '' anziché ‘’.  :-)

Comment: Complici della pigrizia sono i programmi di scrittura che sostituiscono le virgolette e gli apici che si trovano sulla tastiera con i corrispondenti "curvi" (anche quando il risultato è sbagliato come nel caso di `‘sto` invece di `’sto`)

Comment: @Dag, non ho capito la storia dell' "anziché"!

Comment: @martina, intendevo semplicemente che spesso si omette, io per primo, di usare le virgolette (o gli apici) aperte e chiuse (“”) a favore della forma unica per aprire e chiudere ("").

Comment: @Dag La formattazione mi ha fregato, pensavo fosse l'anzichè il virgolettato, invece erano virgolette solitarie. Comunque sono d'accordo, anche io purtroppo non distinguo, eccetto che in LateX che ti obbliga a farlo.

Comment: Credo usare «‘» e «’» sia molto elegante, sebbene siano molti i casi in cui l'uso di ‘«’ e ‘»’ sia inevitabile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Io preferisco adoperare le virgolette alte per evidenziare specifiche parole all'interno di una frase o per una citazione di media lunghezza.

Le virgolette basse preferisco usarle per per evidenziare discorsi nel testo.

La differenza, invece, tra virgolette tipografiche “” e doppi apici " è, secondo me, sostanziale. Le prime servono, appunto, a evidenziare una porzione di testo (distinguendo, tra l'altro, tra apertura e chiusura) le seconde sono usate per indicare, per esempio, un valore numerico (secondi) o un'unità di misura (pollici) a seconda del caso. Le ultime vengono anche usate in programmazione poiché nella maggior parte dei linguaggi di programmazione non è consentito usare caratteri [Unicode](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Comment: In realtà nella maggior parte dei linguaggi di programmazione è consentito usare caratteri Unicode ([qui c'è un esempio](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Unicode_variable_names)), anche se negli identificatori sono consentiti meno spesso che nei letterali stringa. Il problema è che per praticità gli elementi base del linguaggio sono costruiti con i soli caratteri [ASCII](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), che sono quelli che si trovano sulla tastiera americana (e, anche se non con la stessa facilità, su quella italiana). È per la ristrettezza dell'ASCI che si usa `"` e non `“` e `”`.

Comment: Per quanto riguarda l'uso di `"` per indicare secondi (di ora o di grado) o pollici (in entrambi i casi un'unità di misura) in realtà non è corretto. Il [simbolo corretto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29) da usare è `″`, Unicode [U+2033](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2033/index.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Virgolette alte e caporali (come io preferisco chiamare «») sono intercambiabili, nel senso che sono scelte stilistiche della fonte; ogni casa editrice, come diceva DaG, ha il suo manuale di stile. Gli apici semplici sono usati in genere nel discorso virgolettato all'interno di un altro virgolettato.

Poi io per esempio in un testo formale tendo a usare i caporali per le citazioni e le virgolette alte per avvisare che la parola è usata in maniera speciale, ma in un testo meno formale uso "" (e non “”) senza fare quella distinzione.